# How to reproduce Stamen's Toner PostGIS setup?

Tags: postgis, mapnik, stamen

I'm trying to render [Stamen's toner map](https://github.com/Citytracking/toner) with [Landez](https://github.com/makinacorpus/landez) which uses Mapnik. The style I'm rendering is from Stamen's toner project. I'm using the one which only renders labels (no lines). I imported the portion of osm (not planet) using osm2pgsql and I've also ran the motorway script. I have not imported the natural earth, because I cannot download the data (https://github.com/Citytracking/toner/issues/53), but I doubt I need it for text labeling only.

In the style its asking for map source from table (or perhaps view) such as "admin1_labels_50m_z5", but I have no idea the sources of these tables or views? How to create them?

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but admin1_labels_50m_z5 may be the previous name to [these shapefiles in the toner repository](https://github.com/Citytracking/toner/tree/master/mapnik/shp/labels_admin).

Comment: Do you have any idea how to import the shape files?

Comment: See https://github.com/Citytracking/toner on how to import NE files into the database.